# Invalid number of arguments warning after applying util.promisify

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, ide, webstorm

I'm using `stream.pipeline` in Node.js:

```js
import {pipeline} from "stream";

pipeline(file.stream,
        fs.createWriteStream(`${__dirname}${uploaderConfig.savePath}${fileName}`),
        (err) => {}
);
```

Everything is working, no warnings.
Now, I want to get rid of the callback with a help of `util.promisify`:

```js
import {pipeline} from "stream";
import {promisify} from "util";
const asyncPipeline = promisify(pipeline);

await asyncPipeline(file.stream,
        fs.createWriteStream(`${__dirname}${uploaderConfig.savePath}${fileName}`));
```

That's works too, but IDEA shows a warning:

> Invalid number of arguments expected 1
> `const asyncPipeline: (arg1: (NodeJS.ReadableStream | (NodeJS.ReadableStream | NodeJS.WritableStream | NodeJS.ReadWriteStream)[])) => Promise<unknown>`

I assumed that `util.promisify` should just wrap-up the original `stream.pipeline`, returning a promise instead of a callback without changing a function signature. But in fact it looks like, that the signature is overriden, otherwise IDEA wouldn't raise a warning.

My questions:

1. How to solve the warning?
2. Why after applying `util.promisify` the function signature is changed?

Comment: are you using anything to support top-level await. ?

Comment: @CodeManiac, all this code is located inside of  another `async function`, it's not a top-level await.

Comment: Hm, it works fine for me in Webstorm, can't reproduce it.

Comment: @eol, which version of WebStorm do you use?

Comment: @MikeB.: 
`WebStorm 2019.3.4`, 
`Build #WS-193.6911.28, built on March 18, 2020`

Comment: @eol, I'm using 2020.1.1. I also opened a ticket at WebStorm. Let's see, it can be also a regression.